# Accepting and sanitizing JSON blobs via html forms

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have been trying to accept and sanitize JSON blobs via a html form and send the JSON blob using jquery AJAX to a server.

The input JSON blob I accept via html form textarea is something like this

```
{"a":{"b":"c","d":1},"e":true,"f":"test"}
```

When I use JSON stringify to sanitize this, jquery ends up adding \ to every node. for example, the above input would get converted to

```
"{\"a\":{\"b\":\"c\",\"d\":1},\"e\":true,\"f\":\"test\"}"
```

Here is the function I am using to sanitize the JSON input blob before making the AJAX call.

```
 return JSON.stringify(arr_objects);
```

Any pointers on what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there's no such thing as a 'JSON blob'. It's either a JSON formatted string, or an object.

Secondly, the escaped output you see with the `/"` values is because you're calling `JSON.stringify()` on a value which is *already a string*, as you can see in this demo:

```js
var str = '{"a":{"b":"c","d":1},"e":true,"f":"test"}';
console.log(JSON.stringify(str));
```

If all your requirements are is to get a JSON formatted string, then you already have that, and you don't need to do anything to it, to 'sanitize' or otherwise.